# Just how to recode this Java Code Snippet?

Tags: java, code-snippets

I do my review code work, somehow I feel very uncomfortable when saw this Snippet which comes from my workmates:

```
public class ArrayUtil {

    public static List<Integer> joinList(List<Integer> list, Integer data) {
        list.add(data == null ? 0 : data);
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Long> joinList(List<Long> list, Long data) {
        list.add(data == null ? 0 : data);
        return list;
    }

    public static List<Double> joinList(List<Double> list, Double data) {
        list.add(data == null ? 0.00 : data);
        return list;
    }

    public static List<String> joinList(List<String> list, String data) {
        list.add(StringUtils.isEmpty(data) ? "-" : data);
        return list;
    }
}
```

I want to use java generics to recode this Snippet,
but seem it does not have the right way to recode this  Snippet,

Comment: @MDSayemAhmed I think it is more about OOP programming, because you could replace List<String>, List<Double>,.. with List<T> and do some generic coding.

Comment: For a good code review you should find bugs and code which has (serious) problems. So ask yourself, what are the problems with this code. Name the problems and advice some possible direction. Don´t provide your solution as the _better code_. In your example I would name some problems like: 1. the name of the methods don´t explain what the method does. Better rename the method to addToList or provide some good JavaDoc. Why do the methods return the same instance list? This is superfluous. How would this Util-class react on a new requirement like List<Date> ? -> Better use generics.

Comment: public static  <T> List<T> joinList(List<T> list, T data,T defaultVal) {
        list.add(data == null ? defaultVal : data);
        return list;
    }   here is my way， somehow String empty seems ignored！

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have a problem with generics because of the default value.

For the Integer/Long/Date variants you could use ...

```
public class ArrayUtil {
    public static <T> List<T> joinList(List<T> list, T data, T defaultValue) {
        list.add(data == null ? defaultValue : data);
        return list;
    }
}
```

... but is it an improvement to now require the calling code to pass in the default value? And this doesn't handle the empty check for Strings so I think the code is getting worse not better.

If it was me I'd leave the code as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Although [@haggisandchips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2194201/haggisandchips) has a good answer, there are still things that could be improved!

- The naming of the method isn't really clear, name it something like `saveAdd` instead of `joinList`, because `joinList` sounds more like you are going to append a list to another...
- You don't have to return `list`, because it is a *reference* type!
- I'd also suggest returning a `boolean` instead of the actual list. This will give us the power to know when an error has been thrown!

The result:

```
/*
This method will add "data" to your "list".
If data doesn't have a value (null), than it will add the default value.

Will return:
    - true:
        when the value has been added to the list.
    - false:
        when there was an error.
 */
public static <T> boolean saveAdd(List<T> list, T data, Class<T> c) {
    try {
        // If the data is a String but does not contain a value:
        if(c.equals(String.class) && (data == null || data.equals(""))){
            list.add((T)"-");
            return true;
        }

        if(data == null){
            // Default predefined values:
            if(c.equals(Double.class)){
                list.add((T)new Double(0.00));
                return true;
            }

            if(c.equals(Long.class)){
                list.add((T)new Long(0));
                return true;
            }

            if(c.equals(Integer.class)){
                list.add((T)new Integer(0));
                return true;
            }

            // Generic method of creating the default value:
            list.add(c.newInstance());
            return true;
        }

        // Data does contain a value, so we don't have to create one:
        list.add(data);
        return true;

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Didn't work...
    return false;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();

if(!ArrayUtil.saveAdd(test, null, String.class)){
        System.out.println("An error has been thrown!");
}
```